# How to stop Re-Rendering a angular component?

Tags: angular, typescript, rendering, angular13, rerender

I am facing an issue that a component(Home component) re-renders every time when I navigate to other menus, The following is the order of component
Login component -> Home Component -> Child components.
The other components are children of a home component in the router module. Whenever I go to other menus the home component renders every time and the constructor and ngoninit is calling every time. Can anyone know why this is occurring?

This is my routing module,

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
      { path: 'practice', component: AddpracticeComponent,canActivate:[RoleGuard]  },
      { path: 'onboarding', component: OnboardingComponent,canActivate:[RoleGuard] },
      { path: 'order', component: CreateOrderComponent,canActivate:[RoleGuard] },
      { path: 'track', component: TrackComponent,canActivate:[RoleGuard] },
      { path: 'training', component: TrainingComponent,canActivate:[RoleGuard] },
      ]
  },
  
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' },
];
```

```html
<mat-drawer-container class="flex-fill">
  <mat-drawer class="leftmenu" mode="side" opened autoFocus="false">
    <ul
      class="flex-column flex-nowrap h-100 menu nav nav-pills"
      style="width: 100px"
    >
      <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let item of userMenu">
        <a
          *ngIf="item.screenName != 'REPORTS' && item.screenName != 'PRACTICE'"
          class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center nav-link text-center"
          role="tab"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="pill"
          routerLinkActive="active"
          [routerLink]="item.path"
        >
          <img [src]="item.icon" alt="menu-icon" class="menu-icon mb-1" />
          {{item.screenName}}
        </a>

        <a
          *ngIf="item.screenName == 'REPORTS'"
          class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center nav-link text-center position-relative collapsed"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          href="#reportSubmenu"
          role="button"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="reportSubmenu"
          id="reportMenu"
        >
          <img [src]="item.icon" alt="menu-icon" class="menu-icon mb-1" />
          {{item.screenName}}
          <span class="position-absolute" style="right: 5px"
            ><i
              class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"
              style="font-size: 1.5rem"
            ></i
          ></span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content class="bg-white body-content" style="overflow-x: hidden">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Whenever I go to other menus, the home component renders again.

Note: After login and If i refresh the page then the home component not renders.

Thanks

I have tried commenting full code and checked and it is not occuring . It seems like issue is with my code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a custom route reuse strategy. For this create a class like this:

```
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  BaseRouteReuseStrategy,
} from '@angular/router';

export class CustomRouteReuseStrategy extends BaseRouteReuseStrategy {
  shouldReuseRoute(
    future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
  ): boolean {
    return (
      future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig ||
      (!!future.routeConfig?.component &&
        future.routeConfig?.component === curr.routeConfig?.component)
    );
  }
}
```

And in the app.module provide it like this:

```
providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: CustomRouteReuseStrategy },
  ],
```

After that it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have tried the way you said but it does not solve my issue.